# Close XDocument instance

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I have been doing some research on this but still couldn't fix it. I have this function:

```
private void AddNewService()
{
    string strPath = "ServicesToExecute.xml";
    string strServicename = tbNewService.Text;
    //try
    //{
        XDocument xdDocument;
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(strPath))
        {
            xdDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlReader); 

            XElement root = new XElement("Service");
            root.Add(new XElement("Name", strServicename));
            xdDocument.Element("ServicesToExecute").Add(root);
            xmlReader.Close();
            xdDocument.Save(strPath);      
        }
```

And I get an error while trying to save the file... Any idea? I think I am missing something really, really stupid but can't see it by now.

Comment: What exception is thrown when you get the error?

Comment: Why not use the `XDocument.Load` overload that takes a path instead of going through the effort of creating an `XmlReader` and closing it yourself?

Comment: The exception is "An unhandled exception of type System.IO.IOException occured in System.xml.dll" The process can not get access to the file blablabla.xml because it is being used by another process...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're opening a file named `ServicesToExecute.xml` within the `XmlReader` and then trying to save an `XDocument` at the same path... AKA trying to overwrite the file you have open for reading. Per @mikez above, you should probably simplify your code by using the `XDocument.Load(string path)` overload as such:

```
private void AddNewService()
{
    string strPath = "ServicesToExecute.xml";
    string strServicename = tbNewService.Text;
    //try
    //{
        XDocument xdDocument = XDocument.Load(strPath);

        XElement root = new XElement("Service");
        root.Add(new XElement("Name", strServicename));
        xdDocument.Element("ServicesToExecute").Add(root);

        // Save
        xdDocument.Save(strPath);
```

Comment: Sorry.... it idn't work moving the save statement out of the using, neither moving the close ... mmm... still doing research and trying things..

Comment: Save to a different path / filename, or remove the use of `XmlReader` (see my updated answer).

Comment: No.. sorry.. same answer... it worked once.. and later the same.. By the way.. I need to update the same file... as long as I am checkin my services in there and reloading a combobox